# VueJS - How do I design a project that can handle multiple .env file

Tags: vue.js, architecture, environment-variables

#### Current Architecture

So, I have a large scale vue project that serves multiple types of users from multiple subdomains.
I maintain the project through netlify and point specific git branches to specific subdomains.

Let's call them `Site One`, `Site Two` and `Site Three`. I have three separate git branches to control them something like `main`, `mini` and `micro` branch.

Each subdomain/sites or branches has different features turned on or off depending on the targeted users.

I controlled them through a separate `settings.json` file until now. by branching off to different branches, I made separate commits to update the `settings.json` to achieve the behavior of each sites. (Don't think now it's a good idea though)

Here is a rough idea on how the `settings.json` looks like (which varies branch to branch):

```js
{
  available_products: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  feature_one_enabled: false,
  product_journey: 'ZIPPED'
  .....
  mini_mode: true,
}
// and many more flags;
```

#### Flaw

Here comes the pain point, when I find a bug that exists in all the branches and requires fixing in all of them, I can't just merge a branch into another because there were other changes targeted for the other branches.

Also the features incoming are most of the time unique and the current ones are periodically changing.

**Question 1: is it a good practice to keep configuration flags to turn on or off the features in a `.json` file?**
Or should I go with `.env` files.

#### What now

So I have attempted with the fixing of the branch modeling and and keeping the codebase always unique, keeping checks for the configuration setting properties to enable features depending on the branch or the <s>`settings.json`</s> `.env` file.

Followed [this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) branching model btw.

So, the branch and keeping the codebase identical in every branch is solved. Here comes the configurations thing. I can provide different `.env` values to netlify to control the features and all.

But when I am doing local development it will become a bit hassle because I have to set two `.env` file for each branch `(total 6 for { n = 3 branches * 2 modes })`

**Question 2: how can I keep all the `.env` files locally and change them automatically through some `npm` command or branch changes ?**

Or do I have to make some changes to the current architecture?

Comment: Notice that without additional changes in the setup env vars provided by dotenv are strings, so they may be not equal to JSON that has booleans, etc.  *how can I keep all the .env files locally* - I'm not sure if I understood correctly the problem with envs but you probably could make use of .env.*local files and probably generate them with custom script. Not aware of ready to use solution.

Comment: @EstusFlask I am going to parse those values, I have another validator for that. Yes I am aware of the `.env.*.local` and planning to utilize it. But need to find the git branch name through npm script and set the env file accordingly.

Comment: You can have project name in .env itself and load it with dotenv in a script that generates .env.local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answer is for those whoever stumbles upon this question and wonder if I could ever solve this.

##### Yes

I could solve this with the help of a self made plugin and some other helper script files by modifying some vue-cli and webpack configurations.

The concept raised from this [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3328#issuecomment-455788257) discussing if it's possible to **asynchronously** (coming up next) pass some data to the webpack configurations just before running the npm server.

The key solution was using [chainWebpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) for modifying the config.

##### Why asynchronously

Like I said, in order to make the local development painless, I wanted to use `.env` files according to my current `git` branch. But the default command shouldn't be changed and I wanted no extra command for that.

#### Lets code

I used [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) to set my `.env` files and moved the files from the root `/` directory to a subdirectory called `/env`

```
/node_modules
/src
/public
/tests
/env // <- this
```

> Having them in the root directory was messing up the priority of webpack deciding the `*.local` files despite of passing different directory to the config

And the directory now contains files like:

```
.env.branch-one
.env.branch-two
.env.branch-three
.env.branch-four
...
```

Since I wanted a single command to do it all, I added a local plugin and registered my command to npm script. So in my `devDependencies` in `package.json` I added this:

```json
"vue-cli-plugin-dynamic-env": "file:src/plugins/vue-cli-plugin-dynamic-env",
```

And updated the current `run serve` command:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve:auto",
  ...
},
```

Here is the plugin structure (in `/src/plugins/vue-cli-plugin-dynamic-env`):

```
index.js // defines the plugin
generator.js // didn't do much here since it's only local plugin
getCurrentBranchName.js // helper for getting branch name
package.json
```

Now in the `index.js` file, I can import and use `dotenv-webpack` to pass custom env files with the help of `chainWebpack`, and I can use my helper script to get the current git branch to generate the branch name.

And then register a new command `serve:auto` which was previously added to `package.json` and at the end of the command definition, I can programmatically run the built in vue-cli serve command.

Here is how it looks:
:

```js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const activeGitBranch = require('./getCurrentBranchName');

module.exports = (api) => {
  api.registerCommand('serve:auto', async (args) => {
    const branchName = await activeGitBranch(); // getting async value here
    api.chainWebpack((config) => {
      config.plugin('env').use(Dotenv, [{
        // fallback to default file if branch name does'nt match a .env file
        path: branchName ? `./env/.env.${branchName}` : './env/.env', 
        safe: false,
      }]);
    });
    await api.service.run('serve', args); // programmatic call to serve command
  });
};

module.exports.defaultModes = {
  'serve:auto': 'development', // setting default env mode, this is requried.
};
```

If you're wondering what does `getCurrentBranchName.js` file do and how. Here it is:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

module.exports = function currentBranchName() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      // console.log(branchName);
      if (error) { // handle your error
        if (error.code === 128) {
          reject(error);
        }
      }
      if (stderr) {
        reject(stderr);
      }
      resolve(stdout.trim());
    });
  });
};
```

And that's it.

###### Cheers